# Angular Material autocomplete md-input-maxlength not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm try set max length to `Autocomplete` of `Angular Material` with fallowing configuration, but is not working:

```
<md-autocomplete md-input-maxlength='10' md-input-name="autocomplete" data-md-selected-item="myItem" data-md-search-text="searchText"
    data-md-items="item in getMatches(list, searchText)">
    <md-item-template>
        {{item}}
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

I has fallowing the [document](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete), but is not working.

How to can I set max length to `Angular Material autocomplete`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ng-messages` to show validation messages

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']).controller('DemoCtrl', function($timeout, $q) {
    var self = this;
    self.states = loadAll();
    self.selectedItem = null;
    self.searchText = null;
    self.querySearch = querySearch;
    
    $timeout(function() {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('md-autocomplete[md-input-maxlength]');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var minLength = inputs[i].attributes['md-input-minlength'].value,
                maxLength = inputs[i].attributes['md-input-maxlength'].value,
                input = inputs[i].getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0];
            input.setAttribute('minlength', minLength);
            input.setAttribute('maxlength', maxLength);
        }
    }, 500, false);


    function querySearch(query) {
        var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : self.states;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function loadAll() {
        var allStates = 'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware,\
          Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana,\
          Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana,\
          Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina,\
          North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina,\
          South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia,\
          Wisconsin, Wyoming';

        return allStates.split(/, +/g).map(function(state) {
            return {
                value: state.toLowerCase(),
                display: state
            };
        });
    }

    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function filterFn(state) {
            return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0-rc.5/angular-material.css">
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoFloatingLabel" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
        <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()" name="searchForm">
            <div layout-gt-sm="row">
                <md-autocomplete flex md-require-match="" md-input-name="autocompleteField" 
                    md-input-minlength="2" md-input-maxlength="6" 
                    md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
                    md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" 
                    md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" 
                    md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
                    md-item-text="item.display" 
                    md-floating-label="Favorite state">
                    <md-item-template>
                        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
                    </md-item-template>
                    <div ng-messages="searchForm.autocompleteField.$error" ng-if="searchForm.autocompleteField.$touched">
                        <div ng-message="required">You <b>must</b> have a favorite state.</div>
                        <div ng-message="md-require-match">Please select an existing state.</div>
                        <div ng-message="minlength">Your entry is not long enough.</div>
                        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your entry is too long.</div>
                    </div>
                </md-autocomplete>
            </div>
        </form>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: So md-max-length is not for limit type characters like `HTML maxlength` attribute, is for validation?

Comment: yes.. i added a `$timeout` function to update all `inputs` with `min` and `max` lenths. it should now work like you expected